# How to make Q lookups in django look for multiple values

Tags: python, django, search, django-q

Currently I have a very simple search option which goes through my pages and looks up through several fields for requested query. If I input a single word in it it works just fine, however if I input multiple words in search query, I get nothing, even if a single page contains all attributes. For example if I search for `test admin`, I will not get empty query, even though there's a page with title test, with content test and author admin. Is there a way to expand the search to look up each word in search query individually?

```
# Fetch all pages and sort them alphabetically
queryset = Page.objects.all().filter(archived=False).order_by("title")

# Get search query if applicable
query = request.GET.get("q")
if query:
    queryset = queryset.filter(
        Q(title__icontains=query) |
        Q(content__icontains=query) |
        Q(user__username__icontains=query) |
        Q(user__first_name__icontains=query) |
        Q(user__last_name__icontains=query)
    ).distinct()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking for something like the following, where you filter by each individual word in the query:

```
import operator

queryset = Page.objects.all().filter(archived=False).order_by("title")

query = request.GET.get("q")
if query:
    words = query.split()
    fields = ["title__icontains", "content__icontains", "user__username__contains",
              "user__first_name__icontains", "user__last_name__icontains"]

    q_expression = [Q(f,w) for f in fields for w in words]
    queryset = queryset.filter(reduce(operator.or_, q_expression))\
                       .distinct()
```

However, at this point doing search this way gets a little bit messy. If your app grows and you need to search over several models, consider looking into an external search package such as [Haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/).

Comment: Well after spending days stuck on this issue, I've decided to go with a package instead. Haystack seems to do the work perfectly. The reason I'm hesitant to use packages, is that this project is also my own way of learning django from scratch and develop apps on my own. However searching the whole site and all of it's apps contents is extremely complex and for now I'll use the pacakge, and leave searching and indexing on my own for later. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: ```from functools import reduce```